# What is happening with stdout inside function?

Tags: command-line, bash

```
If I run the following command I get the expected output as shown.
jonathan@Aristotle:~/EclipseWorkspaces/AGI/ShellUtilities$ df --output=fstype,source $(pwd)
Type Filesystem
ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

If I place the same command in a function and invoke the function from the command line I see no output. Where has stdout gone and why?

```
#
# Copyright © Jonathan Gossage, 2016
#
# getFileSystemInfo
#

function getFileSystemInfo {
    # Get an item of information related to the file system that contains a
    # specific file or directory.
    # $1 is the file or directory to be checked
    # $2 is the specific information type to be checked. See df(1) FIELD_LIST
    #    for full details. As in df you can get more than one type of
    #    information.
    # To access the information returned, capture stdout in your script.
    echo "We are in getFileSystemInfo"
    df --output=$2 "$1"
    return $?
}
jonathan@Aristotle:~/EclipseWorkspaces/AGI/ShellUtilities$ Sourced/getFileSystemInfo $(pwd) fstype,source
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fill in the exact steps you took: it looks to me like you have created an executable *script called* `getFileSystemInfo` in subdirectory `Sourced` - that's not the same as sourcing a function definition within the current shell.

Comment: The script is intended to be sourced but at the moment the real script, (this is an extract) is being run as a script.

Comment: Well if you want to do that, you will need to add a line to the script that calls the function with its parameters e.g. `getFileSystemInfo "$@"`. Otherwise, you're just invoking a script that (by itself) takes no parameters and does nothing.

Comment: You are right. I completely missed that. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `stdout` in your example: wrapping a shell function definition in a script file and then calling the script does not execute the function. You need to either *source* the script so that the function becomes available in the current shell

```
. Sourced/getFileSystemInfo
getFileSystemInfo $(pwd) fstype,source
```

or modify the script so that it calls the function and passes its own arguments into it by adding a line such as

```
 getFileSystemInfo "$@"
```

Right now, you are simply calling a script that does nothing, with positional parameters that are ignored.